# How many roundtrips does Entity Framework use to insert parent with its child?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Assume I have the following lines of code:

```
var stdAddress = new StudentAddress()
{
  State = "CA",
  Country = "USA"
};

var std = new Student()
{
  Name = "Steve",
  Address = stdAddress
};

using (var context = new SchoolContext())
{      
  context.Add<Student>(std);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When the code is executed, the data of both `Student` and `StudentAddress` are inserted successfully. In case auto-generated ID for the both tables, I just wonder how could **Entity Framework** get exactly the `StudentId` value for inserting `StudentAddress` to the database.

I think there are two round trips to database:

1. Insert `Student` data and returned the `StudentId`
2. EF would use returned `StudentId` value for inserting `StudentAddress` data

Am I correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you turn EF Core [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) on and see what it does (not only for this operation)

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev for good suggestion. I will try it!